# Паскаль. Расставить буквы из алфавитного порядка в слово

Tags: массивы, строки, pascal, freepascal

У меня есть код сортировки букв слова в алфавитный порядок. Например слово "пеликан" он превращает в "аеиклнп". Как сделать обратный порядок - чтобы он "аеиклнп" делал обратно в "пеликан"?

Я пытался сделать еще строку со словом "пеликан", чтобы он сравнивал ее с "аеиклнп" и менял буквы до тех пор, пока они не будут одинаковы, но так не получается.

```pascal
var
  str,strr: string;
  i,j,n: integer;
  ch: char;
begin
  write('Введите слово: ');
  readln(str);
  strr:=str;
  n:=length(str);
  for i:=1 to n-1 do
    for j:=i+1 to n do
      if str[i]>str[j] then
      begin
        ch:=str[i];
        str[i]:=str[j];
        str[j]:=ch;
      end;
   writeln('Результат:');
   writeln(str);

end.
```

P.S. я знаю по поводу регистра, и знаю как исправить, надо просто заранее переместить все в один регистр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  str,strr,strrr: string;
  i,j,n: integer;
  ch: char;
begin
  write('Введите слово: ');
  readln(str);
  strr:=str;

  n:=length(str);
  for i:=1 to n-1 do
    for j:=i+1 to n do
      if str[i]>str[j] then
      begin
        ch:=str[i];
        str[i]:=str[j];
        str[j]:=ch;
      end;
   writeln('Результат:');
   writeln(str);

   strrr:=str;
   for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to n do
      if strr[i]=str[j] then
      begin        
        strrr[i]:=str[j];
        break;
      end;
   writeln('Результат обратный:');
   writeln(strrr);
end.
```

Comment: Да, я как раз только что пришел к этому! Но все равно спасибо большое!

Comment: Я не понимаю, что делает последний двойной цикл. По-моему, он ничего не делает: `strrr := strr;`

Comment: @Igor strrr := strr; присваивается значение "аеиклнп", это нужно для того, чтоб задать переменной strrr одинаковую длину.